# How to Start New Activity from ArrayAdapter through button?

Tags: java, android

I want to start a new activity from my Adapter Activity to another activity through button . Im new in android studio , and i have search throughout some topics , i find some solution, but still didnt fix in my code,they keep telling different errors . please help me .

i want to move it to `ReserveActivity.java` through `btn_reserve` but when i run the code above, it said

`Error:(54, 28) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<ReserveActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)`
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
(argument mismatch;  cannot be converted to Context)

so heres my code

```
public class mainmodeladapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

private Context mContext;

public mainmodeladapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.modelmain, itemname);
        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.modelmain, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lapangantxt);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.hargatxt);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Rp 150.000/Jam");

    return rowView;
    Button btn_reserve = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reserve);
    btn_reserve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ReserveActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
};
}
```

ive searched in another thread, it said that i need to put `context.startActivity(i)` since it's adapter ,coz when i delete the `context.` from `startActivity(i);` , it start showing red highlight

so do the `rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reserve);` if i remove the `rowView.` the `findviewById();` will start having red highlight , i wonder why . am i misplaced the "btn" code?should it be in another activity? 
please help me . Thanks

Comment: in `Intent i = new Intent(this, ReserveActivity.class)` `this` means current class and the current class is `OnClickListener`. You can't pass listener to the first arg of `Intent` constructor. It is a compile time error and i don't know why your compiler doesn't able to find it. Anyway you should READ error before posting it to SO, the message is pretty clear

Comment: ive changed it into `(context, ReserveActivity.class)` miracely , it works , but i dunno why when i press the "reserve" button it crash on the apps . anyway to confirm how to know the crash come from ? im really new in debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can say mainmodeladapter.this as the first argument for the intent.

Answer (score 0):

You should also pass **same activity contex**t in the first argument of intent.

```
 btn_reserve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context /* note here I am using context*/,ReserveActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i try to add `context.this` but it said error cannot find symbol class context 
when i do `context.mainmodeladapter.this` the mainmodeladapter got red highlight

Comment: I didn't say `context.this`, just add **context** like I added in the code. I said `note this`, mean have a look, I am not using `this` here but `context.`

Comment: did you mean by using `context.mainmodeladapter` in my case ? i've just try it and the `mainmodeladapter` are red highlight now

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(context ,ReserveActivity.class);` write it like this.

Comment: `Error:(50, 16) error: unreachable statement`  and `Error:(58, 5) error: missing return statement` there now , sir

Comment: You should write `return rowView;`, at the end of function, not before button click listener. Try understanding what you are writing.

Comment: and i've tried that too , i put the return rowView; after`});` it works , but when i try in my phone , and i click the reserve button , it crashed

Comment: Check your logs and figure out why it crashed. Search on google if you need and try to understand what the error is saying.

Comment: should i add some code on the "reserveactivity" side ? like catching the mainmodeladapter code ?